# Start Text to speech at new remote notification

Tags: ios, notifications, text-to-speech

for an iOS app (iOS 13.x > latest) we need to be able to have the iphone read content of an incoming remote notification with text to speech.

After reading apples documentation and days of googleing, i couldn't find any supported solution.

Question:

- is it possible to have an iphone starting a text to speech (AVFoundation Framework) in a Notification **Service** Extension?
- is it possible to have an iPhone starting a text to speech (AVFoundation Framework) in a Notification **Conent** Extension?
- if not, is there any other stable way to have an iphone reading the notification title as a notification arrives?

Our application has a critical alert entitlement granted. The TTS shall also work if the iPhone is set to "do not disturb".

Best Regards